# Excel 2010, linking table cells to cells on other sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I want to fill table cells by linking to cells on other worksheets eg **=BLACK!B4** in one cell then **=AQUA!B4**, **=BLUE!B4** etc in the cells below.

Unfortunately, when I enter one of these references all the other cells in the column change to reference the same sheet.

Can I overcome this?

Comment: Have you tried absolute references using a `$`

Answer (score 0):

You can turn this behaviour off.  After you insert a formula in a table the Autocorrect Option link will apear (lightning bolt symbol).  From this menu select 'Stop Automatically Creating Calculated Columns'

[image]

These setting are also accessable from Options/Proofing

[image]